# Mongo query to find record between specific time

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collections with `DateTime` field which have datetime value saved in UTC, with time.

I like to find all record between time 8 AM to 6 PM regardless date. I have tried following query:

```js
{ $expr: { $gte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 8 ]} }
```

This query is working fine to get record after 8 AM, regardless date.
I am unable to find query with `$lte` in same match. This query is not working:

```js
{ $expr: { $gte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 8 ], $lte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 18 ]} }
```

> Error: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 8 ], $lte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 18 ] }

Any help would be appreciated. If this can be done in Mongo dotnet core then that would be great using lamda expression.

Comment: You need to wrap the 2 conditions with `$and` like `{$expr:{$and:[{$gte:[{$hour:"$DateTime"},8]},{$lte:[{$hour:"$DateTime"},18]}]}}` ?

Comment: @ray Yes, `$and` is working! It is possible build query with Hour:Minute part? Like between 8.30 AM to 6.30 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simple ways to perform time-only comparison will be convert to string using `$dateToString` and perform string comparison.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                "$dateToString": {
                  "date": "$DateTime",
                  "format": "%H:%M:%S"
                }
              },
              "08:30:00"
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              {
                "$dateToString": {
                  "date": "$DateTime",
                  "format": "%H:%M:%S"
                }
              },
              "18:30:00"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XOUdOBTiHcr) for your reference.